# Is type extending supported by AppSync GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

According to GraphQL spec we can extend a type https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Object-Extensions

This may look like:

```
extend type Group {
  description: String
}
```

The AWS AppSync's UI console allows `extend type` syntax, however, when I save the schema, it simply removes all the `extend type` entries.

[image: AppSync extend type]

Am I doing something wrong, or is type extending not really supported by AppSync?

Comment: doesn't make [a real] sense for single schema?

Comment: @xadm agree. However, the GraphQL spec is not saying that this should not work in the scope of one file.

Comment: Why it should support full graphql specs? I'd said this feature is not worth the effort required to implement it. I wouldn't implement [more valuable] interfaces, too ... it's a SIMPLE schema editor

Comment: I have seen this same issue in amplify (which leverages Appsync) and have yet to find a resolution. I would imagine your answer is no.